VB (.net 8) Two simple Functions which should return same result, but don't
I have a small understanding problem. 2 simple functions that in my opinion should produce the same result, but effectively do not do so.
First (which returns expected values)
  Public Shared Function TSN(value As Object) As TimeSpan?

      If IsDBNull(value) OrElse IsNothing(value) Then
          Return Nothing
      Else
          Return DirectCast(value, TimeSpan)
      End If

  End Function

Second (Which is acting weird in my opinion)
  Public Shared Function TSN(value As Object) As TimeSpan?

      Return If(IsDBNull(value) OrElse IsNothing(value), Nothing, DirectCast(value, TimeSpan))

  End Function

Given Value is coming from an SQL query. If it's Value is DBNull or Nothing, the Functions should both return Nothing. First one does, second returns New Timespan(0,0,0). But i don't get it, because the 2nd function is actually just the short form of the first function.
I'm obviously missing something? Maybe someone here can explain it to me :)

If the value is coming from an ADO.NET query then there's no point testing for Nothing because you'll never get it. If there's no value in the database then you'll always get DBNull.Value.

The If operator has to have a specific type picked from the types of its operands.
Nothing is special and doesn't have a type, or rather it's convertible to every possible type. The other type is TimeSpan (not TimeSpan?) so that's the type determined to be the result type of the If operator.
And so Nothing is converted to the 0 timespan and that's the result.

From the Specification:

The result type of the expression is the dominant type between the types of the second and third expression. If there is no dominant type, then a compile-time error occurs.


An important point specific to this question. Nothing is converted to the 0 timespan and that's the result because TimeSpan is a struct. A reference type being assigned Nothing will be Nothing. Value types like struct will have their default value.

The accepted answer is correct in explaining why your code doesn't work. But your code has a flaw which can make it work. Use TimeSpan? which will correctly return one in both cases.
Public Shared Function TSN(value As Object) As TimeSpan?
    Return If(IsDBNull(value) OrElse IsNothing(value), Nothing, DirectCast(value, TimeSpan?))
End Function

You can also use generics to enforce this. Passing the type will make it clear what you are getting back:
Public Function TSN(Of T)(value As Object) As T
    Return If(IsDBNull(value) OrElse IsNothing(value), Nothing, DirectCast(value, T))
End Function

Dim result1 = TSN(Of TimeSpan?)(Nothing)
Dim result2 = TSN(Of TimeSpan)(Nothing)


Nothing
 00:00:00

It should be clear at this point that passing TimeSpan as the type is not what you want to get back. If you are doing this with types other than TimeSpan? this function could be reused.
There are also ways to do those checks without Microsoft.VisualBasic
TypeOf value Is DBNull
value Is Nothing

IsNothing boxes everything into an object, while Is Nothing doesn't. But you are doing that anyway with your value As Object so these two methods will work the same in your case.
